# VSCode Comments aren't inline

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use VSCode and I think its a great editor, but when I write a comment in html it drops to a new line under what I'm commenting which is really irritating.

If I comment a closing div I want it next to the closing div not under it.

I have uninstalled prettier but that made no difference.

Is what I want even possible in VSCode?

Any advise would be appreciated because I am so irritated that I am considering using a different editor (I'm on a Mac just in case it matters).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Comments are on the same line for me.  Disable all installed extensions - click the `...` with the Extension panel open in the sidebar and see if it still happens.

Comment: @mark I disabled all my extensions but it did'nt help :-(

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem for me too, as were other new line / white space related HTML issues.

Assuming you are not using *any* formatters besides the native VSCode HTML language features (you said you uninstalled prettier, but you didn't mention whether you were using something else),

there is a setting  `HTML white space` which you can set to `preserve` to leave your comments untouched.

Note that you may need to go into settings and check what is being used as the `HTML default formatter`

Comment: Hi, I have disabled all vscode extensions. I have search through the settings but can't find HTML white space, shame because it sounds like it might be perfect. Have you any suggestions how I can find it?